# Two waypoints for two selectors

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I want that when I scroll down, if the distance between my second box (`text1`) and the top of the viewport is 200, this div should have fixed position, and when the distance between the third box (`text2`) and the top of the viewport is 400, `text2` becomes fixed and `text1` is made relative again. When the distance between `text1` and viewport's top gets to 100, `text2` should be relative again and scrollable.
For now, the text1 div gets fixed position when the offset is 200 but text2 doesn't become fixed when it's offset is 400.

Here's a fiddle of what i have done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/cwwy9aq3/2/

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="background-fixed"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div id="text1" class="text text1"></div>
    <div id="text2" class="text text2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.test {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 3000px;
}

.background-fixed {
    background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/17/20/36/christmas-993304_960_720.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
}

.text {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
}

.text1 {
    top: 1100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 225px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.text2 {
    left: 650px;
    top: 1500px;
    width: 419px;
    height: 174px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```js
$('#text1').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === "down") {
        $(this).css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '200px'
        });
        $('#text2').css({
            'top': '3000px'
        });
    }
}, {
    offset: '200'
}).waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === "down") {
        $('#text2').css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': '1500px'
        });
    }
}, {
    offset: '100'
});

$('#text2').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === "down") {
        $(this).css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '400px'
        });
        $('#text1').css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': '1100px'
        });
    }
}, {
    offset: '400'
});
```

Comment: Did you try Google? I.E.: `distance between element and top page`

Comment: I have to use waypoints plugin. The distance between element and top of viewport is that offset.

Comment: I think the problem is that i used fixed positioning on a waypoint element.